# sql query count for sum of two "unknown" columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to query for the COUNT of rows that fulfill multiple filter criteria. However, I do not know which filters will be combined, so I cannot create appropriate indexes.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl WHERE filterA > 1000 AND filterD < 500
```

This is very slow since it has to do a full table scan. Is there any way to have a perfomant query in my situation?

```
 id, filterA, filterB, filterC, filterD, filterE
    1, 2394, 23240, 8543, 3241, 234, 23
```

Comment: Not really.  Inequalities on multiple rows is not a SQL forte.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What would be an alternative? I think NoSQL also has the same restrictions regarding indexes. ElasticSearch maybe?

Comment: . . An R-Tree index structure can  handle this type of query (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).  I'm not sure what tools have this built-in in a general purpose way.  They are usually used for geographic searches.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that there are certain limitations in how you can index data on multiple criteria.  These are standard, fundamental issues and to the extent that ElasticSearch is able to get away from the problems it is just brute force parallelism and indexes on everything you may want to filter by.

Usually some filters will be more commonly used and more selective, so usually one would start by looking at actual examples of queries and build indexes around the queries which have performed slowly in the past.

This means you start with slow query logging and then focus on the most important queries first until you get everything where it is tolerable.